# Excel/Word VBA save as fillable PDF

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, ms-word

is there a way to save a word document as a fillable formated PDF? The line I use to save it as a regular pdf is:

```
wordObject.SaveAs2 fileName:=fileName, FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF
```

Comment: There's only one [`wdSaveAsFormat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839952.aspx) to specify a PDF. A quick google search suggests that while you can create a PDF from Word, you need to use Acrobat to make it "fillable" and specify which fields/forms are fillable by the user. https://langlit.ucdavis.edu/technical-support/create-fill-able-pdf-word-document